# How to write sql query to find wealth of person?

Tags: sql

I am having trouble writing a query that returns the names of all people that have less than half of the wealth of the richest person. We define the wealth of a person as the total money on all of his/her accounts.

The 3 tables are:

```
Persons

id | name | address | age | eyeColor | gender

BankAccounts

id | balance

AccountOf

id | person_id → Persons | account_id → BankAccounts
```

Can anyone help me please

```
SELECT Persons.name
FROM Persons P1
LEFT JOIN AccountOf A1 ON A1.person_id = P1.id
LEFT JOIN BankAccounts B ON B.id = A1.account_id
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(B.balance) < MAX((SELECT SUM(B.balance) as b
  FROM AccountOf A1
  LEFT JOIN BankAccounts B ON B.id = A1.account_id
  GROUP BY A1.person_id ORDER BY b DESC  LIMIT 1)
) * 0.5;
```

Comment: What did you try so far, what exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I just edit my question. Please check.

Comment: What's your database

Comment: @James MYSQL is my database

Comment: What is wrong with your query? If you use P1.name instead of Persons.name in the first line of your select, this should be correct? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a850b844cd9b1073887582268968348

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided any sample data or DBFiddle so this is naturally untested, however you could use a CTE* to construct a query thus:

```
with p as (
    select p.name, Sum(b.balance) balance
    from persons p
    join accountOf a on a.person_id = p.Id
    join BankAccounts b on b.Id = a.account_id
    group by p.name
)
select *
from p
where p.balance < (select Max(balance) from p) * 0.5;
```

(* Requires MySql 8+)

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am getting empty result.

Comment: I would be happy to double check but unfortunately that requires sample data.